# express gateway log every request

Tags: node.js, express, express-gateway

I would like to log every single request that express gateway receives, but it seems I can't decide what to log .

I tried to integrate `morgan('immediate')`
From https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

```
 /* Create a sub app */
  const subApp = express();
  subApp.use(registration({ container }));
  subApp.use(guestRequest({ container }));
  subApp.use(statistics({ container }));
  subApp.use(deleteUser({ container }));
  subApp.use(relationRequest({ container }));

  subApp.use('/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, options));
  subApp.use(morgan('immediate'))
  subApp.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
  subApp.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  subApp.set('views', viewsPath);
```

but it looks like its not being used.

Anyone successfully integrated advanced logging in express gateway ?

I also tried Longjohn and same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Express Gateway out-of-the box.

First, define an apiEndpoint for all requests:

```yaml
    apiEndpoints:
      all:
        host: "*"
        paths: "*"
```

Then, set up a [pipeline](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/configuration/gateway.config.yml/pipelines/) which [logs](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/log/) all requests hitting this apiEndpoint:

```yaml
    policies:
      log

    pipelines:
      logRequest:
        apiEndpoints:
        - all
        policies:
        - log
          - action:
              message: "{req.method} {req.originalUrl} ${JSON.stringify(req.headers)}"
```

If you need to log more, consider enabling Express Gateway and/or Express diagnostic logging using the environment variables:

- `LOG_LEVEL=debug` (for Express Gateway)
- `DEBUG=express:*` (for Express.js)

Comment: Thank you, I already added this but its not enough i want more logs, and I'm getting the error `[EG:policy] socket hang up` that i want to debug, so i need more flexibility to get everything i want

Comment: Actually Thank you, your answer was really helpful, I wasn't doing it on "all" endpoint, and now I'm getting somewhere, but is this all the flexibility I can get? if I want to go deeper into node is it possible ?

Comment: @DanyY, can you update your question to include what you have tried and what you need?

Comment: @DanyY, I have added a section on enabling debug logging which might help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I actually used this thank you.